# javascript regex alphanumeric at list 1 letter

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for an alphanumeric Regex using Javascript that must have atlist 1 letter, so the string CAN'T be all numbers.
666 = invalid
a666 = valid

tried to look for a regex like this all over the web couldn't find one.
was hoping you can help me out.

Comment: Or, to match a string with only letters or digits, but not only digits: `/^[A_Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$/`, which I suspect was what was wanted. (Depends on what is meant by _alphanumeric_.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?![0-9]+$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

Try this.This will make sure you have at least one digit through `negative looahead`See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/43

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                         times (matching the most amount
                         possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                         the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-zA-Z0-9]+             any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z',
                       '0' to '9' (1 or more times (matching the
                       most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                       string
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookahead based regex.

```
^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z\d]+$
```

Positive lookahead `(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])` at the start asserts that the string going to match must contain atleast one letter. If yes, then only follwoing one or more letter or digit would be matched. `^` asserts that we are at the start and `$` refers to the end of a line.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aN0hA3/1)